# Why is my Entity Name an empty String and how can I change the name

Tags: ios, objective-c

I was wondering why is my entity name an empty String? I originally changed the entity name and then I also left the name alone and both times the log message showed that it was empty. I have already checked the context and entity and they are both non-nil values.

```
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self.fetchedResultsController managedObjectContext];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [[self.fetchedResultsController fetchRequest] entity];
entity.name = @"Entity";

NSLog([entity name]);
if ([entity.name length] == 0){
    NSLog(@"String is empty");
}
```

Why is my entity name empty and where/how can I change the name?

#### See also:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24577296/entityforname-nil-is-not-a-legal-nsmanagedobjectcontext-parameter-searching-f

Comment: Is `entity` equal to `nil`? Any method invoked on a `nil` object does nothing.

Comment: As mentioned in the post I have already checked the entity and context's value, and they are both non-nil values. I used a simple if-conditional to check both.

Comment: Can you show the complete code that creates the fetch request?

Comment: Duplicating your own question is not a very good practice... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24577296/entityforname-nil-is-not-a-legal-nsmanagedobjectcontext-parameter-searching-f

Comment: I believe that this question is a related question that is fundamentally different. My previous question concerned the exception that resulted, this question concerns the actual entity name. I believe I'm within the same grounds... http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10841/how-should-duplicate-questions-be-handled

Comment: Either your fetchedResultsController or its fetchRequest must be nil. Post your setter method for self.fetchedResultsController or put some log statements to check that property is valid.

Comment: I checked with Log Statements and the output was that the FetchedResultsController is not nil, the ManagedObjectContext is not nil and the FetchRequest is not nil.